# Determine all real numbers x for which there exist 3*3 real matrices AB-BA such that

Tags: linear-algebra

$A B - B A = \left( \begin{array} { c c c } { 1 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ { 0 } & { x } & { 0 } \\ { 0 } & { 0 } & { - 1 } \end{array} \right)$

I know the matrix AB-BA will corresponding to the matrix of quadratic form, but I found it’s hard to deal with the AB-BA in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What is the trace of the left hand side expression?

Comment: So Tr(AB-BA)=0=1+x+(-1), x=0 is the only answer of the problem, right?

Comment: Yes, $x=0$ is the only option. Now you have to make up two matrices $A, B$ such that $AB-BA=\pmatrix{1 \\&0\\&&-1}$.